# How can I specify a CSS class name declaratively in Vaadin 8?

Tags: java, css, vaadin, vaadin8, declarative

I want to style a component that is specified declaratively in html using css (e.g. specify the `class` attribute for the given component). I know that this is possible by using the Java API like this:

```
Label label = new Label("This is a test label");
label.addStyleName("large");
```

However, I want to achieve the same effect, but with [declarative design](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/application/application-declarative.html).
I already tried to simply specify the `class` attribute in the html tag, but this has no effect:

```
<v-label class="large">This is a test label</v-label>
```

The component that is rendered in the webpage does not retain the classname `large`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you are exactly asking for. But if you ask for Java API to define class name of the component, you should do it as follows

```
Button billedBtn = new Label("Billed");
label.addStyleName("billed-button");
```

If you are using Designer you can edit the style name in Properties, see the picture

[image]

And in declarative format it looks like this

```
    <vaadin-button icon="fonticon://FontAwesome/f153" style-name="billed-button" plain-text _id="billedBtn">
      Billed 
    </vaadin-button>
```

Comment: I updated the question to make clear that I am looking for a way to achieve this by using declarative design.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, I edited the answer to show all the options

Comment: Thank you very much, the `style-name` attribute was what I was looking for.